# Open filehandle not working under mod_perl ModPerl::PerlRun

Tags: perl, mod-perl2

I'm at my first attempt to use mod_perl. I'm totally new to it. I opted for [`ModPerl::PerlRun`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/mod_perl/docs/api/ModPerl/PerlRun.pod) because I don't want to make any modification to the scripts I already have

I followed the instructions in [***Installing Apache2/Modperl on Ubuntu 12.04***](http://41j.com/blog/2012/09/installing-apache2modperl-on-ubuntu-12-04/)

I uploaded `script.pl` to `/perl`, and the script *looks like* it's running fine except for this

```
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', 'page_template.htm') or die $!;
```

It won't open the file and dies with the message

```
No such file or directory at /var/www/perl/script.pl
```

Comment: `-f or warn "please give me full path to $_" for 'page_template.htm';`

Comment: Aswell as check full path check your server has the appropriate permisions.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Note that [the documentation for `ModPerl::PerlRun`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/mod_perl/docs/api/ModPerl/PerlRun.pod) has this to say

> META: document that for now we don't chdir() into the script's dir, because it affects the whole process under threads.

so it is probably not workable to simply do a `chdir` in your program's code, and the second option below should be used

---

**Original***

The current working directory of your CGI program isn't what you think. It is most likely to tbe the root directory `/`

You can either use `chdir` to set the working directory of the script

```
use File::Basename 'dirname';
chdir dirname(__FILE__);
```

or simply add the full path to the name of the file that you want to open, for instance

```
open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', '/perl/page_template.htm' or die $!;
```

Note that you can't use `FindBin`, as your program is being run as a subroutine of Apache's main mod_perl process, so `$FindBin::Bin` will be equal to the directory of the Apache executable `httpd` and not of your own program file

Comment: I have not tested your solution yet 'cause before reading it i found on Apache docs what i could use ModPerl::PerlRunPrefork instead of ModPerl::PerlRun and it solved the problem. But i don't really know if it does have any disadvantage over your solution? I do use prefork anyway 'cause i don't know if all the modules i use are thread safe.